# Rails CanCan overly permissive with hash of conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, cancan

I'm having an issue with CanCan allowing access, when I don't think it should, when using a hash of conditions.

I have a rails model/table called **projects**, which controls access to documents and collections (sets of documents). Projects may be accessed by multiple users, called **collaborators**, if given permission by the project owner.  There is also a collaborators table that tracks which users have access to which projects.

This all works as expected for read only access using a single permission or a single nested permission.  For example, this works for collaborators:

```
can :read, Project, :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id }
can :read, Collection, :projects => { :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id } }
can :read, Document, :collection => { :projects => { :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id }}}
```

I have a case where users other than the owner may need to manage a project. I call these users "editors".  To check for editors I have a boolean field in the collaborators table called "editor".  To allow editors access I created the following hash of conditions in CanCan:

```
can :manage, Project, :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id }, :collaborators => { :editor => true }
```

However, this grants manage access to *all* collaborators if the editor field is true for *any* collaborator.  I only want to grant manage access to a collaborator if the collaborator is also an editor, all other collaborators should only have read access.  Since the above ability dose not work, I have an idea that what I need is something like this:

```
can :manage, Project, :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id AND :editor => true}
```

But I don't know how to do this.  We are using PostgreSQL as our database if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: can :manage, Project, :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id, :editor => true}

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have solved the problem.  I'm going to recommend this example be added to the official CanCan documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the documentation when it talks about passing a [hash of conditions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions). The syntax should not use an `AND` but just a regular Hash:

```
can :manage, Project, :collaborators => { :user_id => user.id, :editor => true}
```

Comment: Thanks, I miss-interpreted the documentation but its clear now.